# Cannot get Video.js to import using Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I've downloaded Video.js using npm, but I'm having trouble getting it imported to use it on the front end.  Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Installed Video.js with npm, and the `/node_modules` directory was created.
2. Added code to `webpack.mix.js` at the beginning of the file.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'videojs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js'),
        }
    }
});
```

3. Ran `npm run dev` successfully.
4. added below code to view `play.blade.php`:

play.blade.php

```
 <script type="module">
    import 'videojs';

    videojs('my-player');
    </script>
```

I get this error **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "videojs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Why is it searching for a path when I'm using an alias?

I've tried so many variations of getting the package to import and no success, been stuck for 2 days.  How do I solve this?  I want to use video.js in the view.

Answer (score 2):

First, install the latest version of Video.js.

```
npm install --D video.js
```

In [/resources/js/bootstrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/resources/js/bootstrap.js) add...

```
window._ = require('lodash');
require('video.js');
```

Compile your assets...

```
npm run prod
```

Add the following to your layout.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

For reference here's my [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json).

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.2.13",
        "video.js": "^7.11.8"
    }
}
```

And also [webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/webpack.mix.js).

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Then, in the player.

```
<video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    data-setup="{}">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, 
        and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
            supports HTML5 video
        </a>
    </p>
</video>
```

If you want to use the CSS. then include in [/resources/css/app.css](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/resources/css/app.css):

```
@import "~video.js/dist/video-js";
```